# Exception throws during the User Transaction begin method

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb, jta

There is a block of code in Java (a loop) which uses User Transaction for validating the transaction. 
The user Transaction object is declared before the loop.This  method is used to validate certain things.
It is working fine but now frequently getting issue For eg: if the user pass four values three got successfully validated  working fine and one of them got failed 
and nothing shows in the screen. 
        Verified the logs and it shows the as below. I am using ejb Hiberante Persistence and deployed in JBoss.

```
     Unexpected exception occurred
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ut.begin(); 
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor389.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.java:72)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:76)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor289.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
```

Code:  The below code is Bean class of stateful session bean:

```
public Collection<Acknowledgement> goodTransfer(String destLoc,
        String destUT, Collection objectList, boolean getDetails,
        boolean valid, boolean commit, String userId, String pass)
        throws Exception {

    List<Acknowledgement> acks = null;

    if (objectList != null) {
        try {
            ut.begin();
    if (valida) {
                try {
                    acks = GoodUtils.getInstance().validate(userId,
                        destLoc, destUT, objectList,
                        userName, password);
                } catch(GoodException e) {
                    log.error("Transfer failed", e);
                    acks = new ArrayList<Acknowledgement>(1);
                    Acknowledgement ack = new AmcAcknowledgement(false,
                        e);

                    acks.add(ack);
                }
     else {
        throw new Exception(Exception.MISSING_VLUES);
    }


    return acks;        }
```

Please help on this

Comment: `ut` is not even instantiated, that should be a compilation error

Comment: its already instantiated as @Resource EJBContext ejbContext;
  UserTransaction ut;

Comment: @Maxtech Try to check if the ut variable is null before invoking any of its methods.

Comment: You have mentioned `UserTransaction ut` above, however I do not see any annotation on it. Could you share the code block where you inject that.